# How to tackle a 'str' not callable error message

Tags: python

State_city = ('Abia' + 'Umuahia')

Together = State_city

Print(Together)

I'm practicing on pydroid3 and I want to print state_city but I keep getting error messages

I tried adding ' to the print syntax but it still won't print. It keeps outputting 'Str' object is not callable.

Comment: Did you mean `print(Together)`?

Comment: `'print' != print`

Comment: Please consider going through a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) on Python. See this page for more resources: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried this but it only printed together and not the state_city

Comment: It's not at all clear what you expected and how that differs from what you're getting, but you seem to have solved the problem you actually asked about.

Comment: Don't edit the question to remove the question. `print(Together)` (correcting what I assume is an autocorrect-induced typo) would work where `'print'(Together)` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written is 'print' which is a string and not a function. Instead this is the correct way (I have refactored it too):

```py
State_city = 'Abia' + 'Umuahia' # No need for parenthesis/brackets

Together = State_city

print(Together) # it is print and not 'Print'
```